# How to implement user input on a website to go to specific site for scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have been working on a web scraper to get the weather for a specific zipcode. However, I do not know how to use user input on the site to receive the weather for their specidic zipcode

I have not tried much because I am not very familiar with inputing user input

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


r = requests.get(
    "https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.870330000000024&lon=-117.92895999999996"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
week = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast-body")

items = week.find_all(class_="tombstone-container")

period_names = [item.find(class_="period-name").get_text() for item in items]
short_descriptions = [item.find(class_="short-desc").get_text() for item in items]
temps = [item.find(class_="temp").get_text() for item in items]


weather = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Period": period_names, "Description": short_descriptions, "Temperature": temps}
)

print(weather)
weather.to_csv("weather.csv")
```

Comment: you need to create a dictionary which contains the zip codes as key and laongtide and latitude as vlaues ad replace those values from particular zip code in request.get

Comment: What do you mean "on the site"? Is this going to be a web application or a console application?

Comment: Also, is this only going to take zipcodes? What about the rest of us?